# How can I use WP-CLI commands without --allow-root

Tags: wp-query, wp-cli, ssh

I wanted to use WP-CLI commands in my putty WordPress 5.5.1 & Ubuntu 20.04 Droplet but “When I use Wp commands without –allow-root then It shows an error that you are accessing as the root user,” and I know it’s un-secure to use –allow-root. Please Can anyone help me in accessing wp commands in my Putty without –allow-root.

Comment: Is `root` the only user on your droplet? You could (and probably should) create a less-powerful user, give it write access to your website, and then `su {username}` and use `wp` as that user instead.

Comment: I tried it and I create a user with "su adduser" and I know username & password but how can I access it, can log in in my ssh as I log in with root user, or I need to run some command to switch between user.

Comment: If you're logged in as `root`, you should be able to do [`su {username}`](http://www.linfo.org/su.html) where `{username}` is the username you set up. If you're root, it shouldn't ask you for a password.

Comment: Thank you brother, It worked and now, I can use Wp-Cli commands

Answer (score 3):

You can do is to create an additional user and switch to it in order to use the wp-cli

Comment: Yeh! It worked...

Comment: Please upvote my answer and mark it as solution :) so users can benifit